# element.scrollTo Not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So i am making a vertical scrolling carousel, and everything seems to be working great. I am able to scroll horizontally using both buttons and swipe gestures. ON SIMULATOR. When i put the website up on an actual mobile device, i get this error:

`TypeError: e.scrollTo is not a function. (In 'e.scrollTo(i,0)', 'e.scrollTo' is undefined)`

Like i said, this works on multiple browsers and on the mobile simulator, but isnt working on actual device. Here is the code:

```
Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d/2;
  if (t < 1) {
    return c/2*t*t + b
  }
  t--;
  return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};

export default function ScrollTo(element, to, duration) {
  var start = element.scrollLeft,
    change = to - start,
    currentTime = 0,
    increment = 20;

  var animateScroll = function(){
      currentTime += increment;
      var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
      element.scrollTo(val, 0);
      if(currentTime < duration) {
          setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
      }
  };
  animateScroll();
}
```

called via

```
ScrollTo(document.getElementById("sidewaysScroller"), scrollerWidth, 800);
```

Note: I am using ReactJS, and I am reluctant to use a JQuery based solution.

Comment: Maybe it's trivial to say, but log `element` as a starting point.

Comment: ^ that or `JSON.stringify(element)` and append it to body if you don't have access to a console on the mobile device.

Comment: @Kootoopas its definitely finding the element, good idea though didn't even check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `element.scrollLeft = val;` , seems to work pretty well.